# Windows WMI - What is the difference (and order) between Win32_ProcessStartTrace and __InstanceCreationEvent?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Just getting started with WMI, and I am trying to understand what is the difference between **Win32_ProcessStartTrace** and **__InstanceCreationEvent**. They both are available when a new process starts, however which one is first ?

I have tested several examples provided by Microsoft and I cannot see any major difference like performance issues, besides the fact that one provides some useful=l information and the other does not. (or does it?)

From the documentantion for [Win32_ProcessStartTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace) and [__InstanceCreationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/--instancecreationevent)  we can see quite a difference, as the Win32_ provides more details like ProcessID whilst __Instance does not.

If one wants to monitor process creation effectively (asynchronously) which one of these 2 should be used ?

Getting information about the process is a must, at least the ProcessID.

A good explanation is much appreciated, I`m sure others are interested as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_InstanceCreationEvent` has a `TargetInstance` field, which for a new process is a [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) object, which has most of the same fields (and more) that `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` provides.